# Write list of dictionaries to multiple rows in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

So I have a list of dictionaries, that itself has lists of dictionaries within it like this:

```
myDict = [{'First_Name': 'Jack', 'Last_Name': 'Smith', 'Job_Data': [{'Company': 'Amazon'}, {'Hire_Date': '2011-04-01', 'Company': 'Target'}]}, 
 {'First_Name': 'Jill', 'Last_Name': 'Smith', 'Job_Data': [{'Hire_Date': '2009-11-16', 'Company': 'Sears'}, {'Hire_Date': '2011-04-01'}]}]
```

However, as you can see, some of the key values are the same, and sometimes data elements will be missing like Jack missing a Hire Date and Jill missing a company. So what I want to do is preserve the data and write it to multiple rows so that my final output looks like this:

```
      First_Name    Last_Name    Hire_Date     Company
0     Jack          Smith        NaN           Amazon  
1     Jack          Smith        2011-04-01    Target
2     Jill          Smith        2009-11-16    Sears
3     Jill          Smith        2011-04-01    NaN
```

---

Edit: Follow-up question. Say now that I have a dictionary that looks like this that adds in an extract key and I want to produce a similar output but with the new data included:

```
 myDict = [{'First_Name': 'Jack', 'Last_Name': 'Smith', 'Job_Data': [{'Company': 'Amazon'}, {'Hire_Date': '2011-04-01', 'Company': 'Target'}, 'Dependent_data': [{'Dependent': 'Susan Smith'}, {'Dependent': 'Will Smith'}]}, 
     {'First_Name': 'Jill', 'Last_Name': 'Smith', 'Job_Data': [{'Hire_Date': '2009-11-16', 'Company': 'Sears'}, {'Hire_Date': '2011-04-01'}]}]
```

Output:

```
      First_Name    Last_Name    Hire_Date     Company    Dependent
0     Jack          Smith        NaN           Amazon     Susan Smith  
1     Jack          Smith        2011-04-01    Target     Will Smith
2     Jill          Smith        2009-11-16    Sears      NaN
3     Jill          Smith        2011-04-01    NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data=myDict, meta=["First_Name", "Last_Name"], record_path="Job_Data")
print(df)

  Company   Hire_Date First_Name Last_Name
0  Amazon         NaN       Jack     Smith
1  Target  2011-04-01       Jack     Smith
2   Sears  2009-11-16       Jill     Smith
3     NaN  2011-04-01       Jill     Smith
```

Comment: That did the trick thanks! I also edited the post for an additional question that adds more complexity if you happen to have more insight. Not sure if this method can be expanded to tackle the additional complexity or not.

Comment: check the formatting on the new dict